# Maven dependency seemingly coming from nowhere

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I have a jar that I just bumped the version number up on.  It was 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, we bumped it up to 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT since then, but when building one of my projects, it is still looking for the old one.  I have gone through the dependency hierarchy and I cannot find it present anywhere.  Maven, with the debug switch on doesn't display the jar anywhere, but it does complain that the jar is missing.  I've gone through all of my other projects and ensured that 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT is not in any of the poms, but it still gives me problems.  Any idea what to do?

Comment: Have you installed the new version of that project? Post your pom for failing project.

Comment: Can you post the full error output from Maven?

Comment: Reboot + nuke the local repository + mvn clean install solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Can it be included as a transient dependency? Run 'mvn dependency:tree' and see how version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT is brought into your project.